# Mysqli if exists update else update

Tags: mysqli, insert, sql-update

Now i know there are plenty of posts on this subject but no matter how many i read i still cant get this to work.

i have the following code

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM exhibitor_list WHERE companyid='$iscid'" );

if ($result->num_rows > 1){

$mysqli->query("UPDATE `exhibitor_list` (`id`, `company_name`, `description`, `country`, `website`, `logo`, `sponsortype`, `flag`, `facebook`, `twitter`, `instagram`, `youtube`,`facebookshow`, `twittershow`, `instagramshow`, `youtubeshow`, `companyid`) VALUES (NULL, '$companyname', '$description', '$country', '$website', '$file', '$sponsortype', '$countrycode', '$facebook', '$twitter', '$insta', '$youtube', '$facebookshow', '$twittershow', '$instashow', '$youtubeshow', '$iscid')");
}
else {
$mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `exhibitor_list` (`id`, `company_name`, `description`, `country`, `website`, `logo`, `sponsortype`, `flag`, `facebook`, `twitter`, `instagram`, `youtube`,`facebookshow`, `twittershow`, `instagramshow`, `youtubeshow`, `companyid`) VALUES (NULL, '$companyname', '$description', '$country', '$website', '$file', '$sponsortype', '$countrycode', '$facebook', '$twitter', '$insta', '$youtube', '$facebookshow', '$twittershow', '$instashow', '$youtubeshow', '$iscid')");
}
```

it will insert a new field into the database but if the $iscid is already in the 'companyid' table it will not update.

i'm sure i have the code wrong somewhere but just can't figure it out.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Is `$result->num_rows > 1` really meant to be `$result->num_rows > 0`?

Comment: i have also tried 0 but still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

your update command should be replaced by:

```
UPDATE exhibitor_list SET company_name ="....", description ="...." WHERE id = 'your row id'
```

Also Ben Y is right, you should check if the num_rows is greater than 0 instead of 1.

Comment: there null to start with and get given an auto incremental number for their id as a row is successfully inserted. if its used on an update (where the row already has an id) what should NULL be replaced with?

Comment: I think you're executing the update incorrectly. Try to replace the update query with " UPDATE exhibitor_list SET field1 = ..., field2 = ... WHERE id = 'some id', and you dont need to update the id value unless you really want to. google SQL update command. CHeck think link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: I dont think you should update the id value, if you want to have a specific identifier to a row you should create a column like "identifier" with the data type you want. normally id fields when created stay the same even when the row is updated

Answer (score 0):

thanks to user3754262

this is what i have done and works perfect.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM exhibitor_list WHERE companyid='$iscid'" );
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `exhibitor_list` SET company_name='$companyname', description='$description', country='$country', website='$website', logo='$file', sponsortype='$sponsortype', flag='$countrycode', facebook='$facebook', twitter='$twitter', instagram='$insta', youtube='$youtube', facebookshow='$facebookshow', twittershow='$twittershow', instagramshow='$instashow', youtubeshow='$youtubeshow' WHERE companyid='$iscid'");

} else {
    $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `exhibitor_list` (`id`, `company_name`, `description`, `country`, `website`, `logo`, `sponsortype`, `flag`, `facebook`, `twitter`, `instagram`, `youtube`,`facebookshow`, `twittershow`, `instagramshow`, `youtubeshow`, `companyid`) VALUES (NULL, '$companyname', '$description', '$country', '$website', '$file', '$sponsortype', '$countrycode', '$facebook', '$twitter', '$insta', '$youtube', '$facebookshow', '$twittershow', '$instashow', '$youtubeshow', '$iscid')");

 }
```